# Send jquery data to struts action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, struts2

I'd like to send a data from my javascript to my struts action. It's just an id, therefore i wonder if there is a better way than to do it through a form.submit();

here is the variable i'd like to send.

```
var id = $('[data-detailsid="' + $(this).data('headid') + '"]');
```

What would be the proper way to do it ?

My current js function :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "deleteProduct",
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'productId=' + id
});
```

And my struts action :

```
@Action("/deleteProduct")
@ResultPath("/")
@Result(name = "success", location = "jsp/board.jsp")
public class DeleteAction {

    int productId;

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;


    public String execute() {
        Product currentProduct = new Product();
        currentProduct.setId(productId);
        userDao.deleteProduct(currentProduct);
        setProducts(userDao.getProducts());
        return "success";
    }

    public void setProductId(int productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
        }
}
```

Comment: use `$.ajax` to send data to server

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl i'm trying to get the ajax to work but i'm not very used to it. Mind looking at what i did ? I edited my post. I'd like to have my productId inside my action to be set to the id variable in my javascript

Comment: basics are correct in `$.ajax`. Use  success and error handlers for confirmation. I don't know anything about struts... just treat the ajax data as if it was a form submit of an `<input>` with `name="productId`

Comment: I'll give it a try and let you know. But ajax seems pretty darn powerful. My page don't have to reload to fetch data holy moly :')

Comment: As integration to RomanC's answer, any action result will always end inside the success callback (`.done()`), even if you return ERROR, because jQuery knows nothing about action results, it uses HTTP codes to detect the state of a response, and with dispatcher result they'll always be 200. To enter the error callback (`.fail()`), you need to return a `json` result with the `errorcode` param, or an `httpheader` result, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32840288/1654265) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35039017/1654265)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are calling action via Ajax, there isn't necessary to return `dispatcher` result. You can return result type `json` if you have json plugin on the classpash and `@ParentPackage("json-default")` annotation to the action. You can use `root` parameter to the json result to define the object being serialized when result is executed. By default the `root` is set to the action instance, so all properties are serialized. If you want to restrict/allow some properties from json serialization you can use parameters to the result `excludeProperties` and `includeProperties`. Both parameters are mutually exclusive.

```
@Result(type="json", params = {"includeProperties", "productId" })
```

It will return `productId` back to the page if it was populated to the action bean and the action class has a getter method.

You can get the result on success callback function using

```
$.ajax({
    url: "deleteProduct",
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'productId=' + id,
    dataType: "json"
}).done(function(data){
    console.log("The product id:" + data.productId);
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
   alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```